# Indeterminate in checkbox with formControl

Tags: html, angular-material, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have been trying to implement "select all" option with Mat-Select using Mat-checkbox to get the indeterminate option along with reactive forms.
And here is the reference link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-check-all.component.ts

In ts:

```
 @Input() model: NgModel;
  @Input() values = [];

  isIndeterminate(): boolean {
    return this.model.value && this.values.length && this.model.value.length
      && this.model.value.length < this.values.length;
  }
```

And html:

```
<mat-checkbox class="mat-option"
                [indeterminate]="isIndeterminate()"
                [checked]="isChecked()"
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="toggleSelection($event)">
      {{text}}
    </mat-checkbox>
```

I have tried to do it using Reactive forms but I could not implement it as it started to through me errors related to value binding. And I want to implement it with Reactive forms itself.

Comment: the stackblitz link has template driven form... can you share the link of your reactive form?

Comment: I don't have. I was trying the same with Reactive forms and it was throwing errors

Comment: Did you manage to implement 'Select All' with reactive forms?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?